# Can any map $A\to \Bbb C$ be extended to a map $X\to \Bbb C$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Can any continuous map $A\to \Bbb C$ be extended to a continuous map $X\to \Bbb C$?

Here $A\subset X$ is a closed subspace of a $X = Y\times \Bbb R^n$ where $Y$ is compact.

Comment: Elaborate your question...  what kinda extension you want ? continuous ?

Comment: Continous yesss

Answer (score 3):

Yes, $\mathbb{C}$ is a so-called absolute extensor for normal spaces. So if $A$ is closed in a normal (i.e. $T_4$) space $X$, we can extend a continuous function $f: A \to \mathbb{C}$ to a continuous $\overline{f}: X \to \mathbb{C}$ (so $\overline{f}| A =f$). And clearly having the extension property implies $X$ is normal. So your Hausdorff $Y$ should exactly have the property that $Y \times \mathbb{R}^n$ is normal, which is equivalent to $Y$ being normal and countably paracompact (by considering Dowker's theorem, e.g. theorem 5 in [this post](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/tag/countably-paracompact-space/).